# Convert data frame to nested json in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to convert df to nested json with the following code:

```
nested_json = (df.groupby(['prediction_probability','id','ts','prediction_value'], as_index=False)
             .apply(lambda x:x[[
                "first_create_date",  
                "create_date",
                "update_timestamp",
                 "revenue",
                 "col",
                 "x"]].to_dict('r'))
             .reset_index()
             .rename(columns={0:'features'})
             .to_json(orient='records'))
```

My problem is that the nested dict (key ='features') wrapped with square brackets.
How can I avoid the square brackets? I know that I can treat my output as a string and replace the square brackets but of course, this is a bad practice

**Output:**

```
[
    {
        "pred": 0.50726,
        "id": "0030X00002qMwFrQAKxxxx",
        "ts": "2020-02-19T20:32:15.016586",
        "value": "A",
        "features": [
            {
                "first_create_date": 1582089665000,
                "create_date": 1582089665000,
                "update_timestamp": 1582142462000,
                "revenue": null,
                "col":"aaaa",
                "x": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "pred": 0.50895,
        "id": "0030X00002qMvfHQASxxxxx",
        "ts": "2020-02-19T20:32:15.016586",
        "value": "A",
        "features": [
            {
                "first_create_date": 1582077985000,
                "create_date": 1582077985000,
                "update_timestamp": 1582142462000,
                "revenue": null,
                "col":"aaaa",
                "x": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Desired output:**

```
[
    {
        "pred": 0.50726,
        "id": "0030X00002qMwFrQAKxxxx",
        "ts": "2020-02-19T20:32:15.016586",
        "value": "A",
        "features": 
            {
                "first_create_date": 1582089665000,
                "create_date": 1582089665000,
                "update_timestamp": 1582142462000,
                "revenue": null,
                "col":"aaaa",
                "x": null
            }

    },
    {
        "pred": 0.50895,
        "id": "0030X00002qMvfHQASxxxxx",
        "ts": "2020-02-19T20:32:15.016586",
        "value": "A",
        "features": 
            {
                "first_create_date": 1582077985000,
                "create_date": 1582077985000,
                "update_timestamp": 1582142462000,
                "revenue": null,
                "col":"aaaa",
                "x": null
            }

    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple dict comprehension will do the trick:
Say you can reach a nested json shaped like your output and call it `output`. Then, to reach your desired output, the only thing you need to do is to take the first element of the `features` list:

```
desired_output = [{k: v if k!='features' else v[0]} for x in output for k,v in x.items()]
```

Comment: thank u, but now I'm getting this error: " 'str' object has no attribute 'items' " since the JSON is actually a string type

Comment: I added this line: format_json = json.loads(nested_json) and then changed a little bit your code: desired_output = [{k: v if k != 'features' else v[0] for k, v in x.items()} for x in format_json] and it works!! thank u!

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer solved your problem, please accept it (with the little "v" sign) to let others know it's closed.